# what is difference between vps and Dedicated Servers

Tags: web-hosting, vps, dedicated-hosting, cloud, development

I am web developer and I've created an application in nodejs and i want to deploy my app on cloud and i searched everywhere and I've found two options:

> 1.Virtual Private Servers
>
> 2.Dedicated Servers

I am confused which server is good for deployment and my application is not so big. I have to install three applications on server like elastic search, node, mongodb, so which server is good for that?

Comment: Be careful if you are ordering a dedicated server.  Some companies such as godaddy sell what they call a dedicated server, but it is just a fancy VPS where you don't have granular control of things such as inode settings and they won't adjust them to suit your needs.  Needless to say they don't tell you this up front, so ask the question "is this a bare metal dedicated server where I have access to all resources?" (There may be a better question, but that is a good start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**VPS**

Virtual Private Server or Cloud Server model suits small or medium businesses that are looking to optimize their IT infrastructure yet don’t want to incur the higher costs of fully dedicated server hosting. VPS is just like owning a set amount of space in an office building. Virtual private servers provide the performance of a dedicated server running on a machine located in a shared environment. Through root access, customers get the full control of the server just like a dedicated server. So you can install or run any customized software or applications specific to your business needs.

Unlike a shared server, the performance of the websites running on your server is insulated from the other websites. VPS servers give better performance and your websites load much faster than they would on a shared server hosting.

**DEDICATED**

A dedicated server is an ideal solution for the medium or large businesses that have outgrown a VPS server. Dedicated servers provide you the full control or nearly full control over your server for its use. Like a VPS, you may choose the operating system or compatible software of their choice which is most appropriate for your business.

**DIFFERENCE BETWEEN VPS AND DEDICATED**

Majority of the VPS benefits of VPS are also applicable to a dedicated server. However, there are a couple of features that differentiate the two. Unlike VPS, you need to buy or rent the physical server, and also incur costs related to maintenance or management. Dedicated servers are mostly housed in Data centers, similar to collocation facilities, providing redundant power sources and HVAC systems. In contrast to collocation, the server hardware is owned by the provider and in some cases they will provide support for your operating system or application. You may either use a managed or an unmanaged dedicated server as per your convenience.

VPS servers cost far less than a fully dedicated server as you don’t need to buy any physical server or incur costs on managing or maintaining your server. VPS servers allow you to pay as much you use, on a monthly basis. So you pay only for what you have used never charging for anything extra.

VPS also provides you the flexibility to increase or decrease your resources depending on the actual demand. So for example, in case you are foreseeing a heavy traffic during a particular festive season, you can be better prepared by increasing the server specifications accordingly.

Selecting the right server is a crucial decision for your business. Depending your business goals, current requirements, future strategies, growth objectives, you may decide which server, Cloud/ Virtual Private Server or Dedicated Server, will help to meet the growing demand and give your users the best experience.

More reading [**here.**](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/difference-between-shared-vps-dedicated-hosting)

Comment: Please cite your sources and indicate that the text is a quote if you cut and paste from a 3rd party website (a hosting company in this case).

Answer (score 1):

I'm late to this question, but you want a VPS here.  (If you need to ask the question, the answer is automatically get a VPS)

A VPS is a VIRTUAL Server.  Its a part of an actual server, but you get full admin access to it.   The advantages are that it costs less if you need less then a full servers worth of power - but more importantly hardware issues are the responsibility of the provider and hardware issues are typically mitigated using redundant shared disk separate from the actual server.  If a server fails the provider just spins up another server to replace the failing one.  Monitoring the server health is the responsibility of the provider.

A dedicated server is a whole server.  This is typically cheaper if you need performance, but means you need to ensure the hardware is not failing - and if it does fail you need a plan B.  (Typically the provider is responsible for replacing failed hardware, but you need to tell them its failing - and handle your own RAID/storage).   Its also worth considering that most dedicated servers use older hardware (ie its often the old virtual server host that has been repurposed once more dense hardware is available)

Answer (score 0):

Every company has its own definition of what VPS is and what Dedicated means.  You really have to read the fine print on the agreements to figure out things.  What you may think of something typical may not carry over from site to site.

In a nutshell why I have decided to go Dedicated:

- More control over server software.  I can run ASP and PHP on the same server.  The hosting company may tell me to go to hell (in a nice way) when I try to open up certain kinds of tickets but I can do this.
- More control over configuration.  I can allocate more memory to certain aspects of my application and I am only limited by the physical means of the server.
- I can throw on 3rd party software.  It sounds stupid but if you are dealing with large apps with precise company configuration there is tons of software that may help you.  I have things that run batch files for me and process large amounts of records.  I could spend potentially 100s of hours of coding or thousands of dollars or pay $300 for the software and install it on my own server.
- Working on the server is presumably much easier.  Yes I have used some decent Control Panels or whatever for VPS solutions but nothing beats remoting directly to the server and making the changes.
- I have Elastic Search running on Windows 2013 and PHP on one of my servers.  I can't imagine or even see how I would have done this properly (resource allocation) through a VPS solution (I am sure running this is very doable in upper level VPS solutions but I have never had the budget to investigate those).
- Most VPS solutions come with a DB choices.  You should definitely find lots of VPS solutions that support MongoDB but you can just install whatever you want on yours - I often have Mongo and MySQL both installed on my dedicated servers.

VPS does have its pluses though.  First it is more flexible in terms of allocating resources and bandwidth.  However you said your application isn't that big so it shouldn't be an issue.  Also the biggest thing with having a dedicated server is that the hosting company will hand of the server to you at some point.  If you don't know how to configure a server or use IIS/Apache/Whatever then you are probably in big trouble.  There are many clients that I would never think about moving to Dedicated as I would be afraid that they would take down their own site.

Comment: I think you are confusing a VPS and what some companies call "cloud hosting" (although I agree the terms aren't always used consistently). Basically everything in your list applies to both VPS' and dedicated servers. You have full root access to a VPS - you can install whatever you want on there, although perhaps things are different in the Windows hosting world.